# multiple conditions formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working on a sales form, that has multiple factors to determine sales commission.
If C4=Implant, and if K4 = >30 through 34%, then return "Tier 1"

seems simple enough, but there are more...

```
Implant 30-33% = Tier 1
Implant 34-38% = Tier 2
Implant 39+% = Tier 3

800Ship 30-34% = Tier 1
800Ship 35-40% = Tier 2
800Ship 41+% = Tier 3

Fulfillment 31-35% = Tier 1
```

and so on

can anyone help me crack this one? In my mind it seems so simple, but I just can't formulate it the way I need to in order to return the value of the tier data.

Comment: How many of these conditions do you have? are they in a table? If yes, can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1405384/edit) to add a screen cap of it (upload it to imgur.com and post a link)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will work:

`=IFS(C4="Implant",IFS(K4>=39,"Tier 3",K4>=34,"Tier 2",K4>=30,"Tier 1"`**`,TRUE,"Implant < 30"`**`),
C4="800Ship",IFS(K4>=41,"Tier 3",K4>=35,"Tier 2",K4>=30,"Tier 1"`**`,TRUE,"800Shipt < 30"`**`),
C4="Fulfillment",IFS(K4>=50,"Tier 3",K4>=36,"Tier 2",K4>=31,"Tier 1"`**`,TRUE,"Fulfillment < 31"`**`)`**`,
TRIM(C4)="","Code is Blank",TRUE,C4&" not found"`**`)`

The categories in the formula (bar) can be organized with a line break by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Delete the bolded code `,TRUE,"Implant < 30"`, `,TRUE,"800Shipt < 30"`, `,TRUE,"Fulfillment < 31"`, `,TRIM(C4)="","Code is Blank"`, `,TRUE,C4&" not found"`, as desired.

IMHO This would be less obscure and considerably easier to maintain using a lookup table such as:

`_____|Column A    |Column B|Column C|Column D`
`Row 1|Code        | Tier 1 | Tier 2 | Tier 3`
`Row 2|Implant     |   30   |   34   |   39`
`Row 3|800Ship     |   30   |   35   |   41`
`Row 4|Fulfillment |   31   |   36   |   44`

with the formula:

`=IFNA(INDEX(TierSht!$B$1:$D$1,MATCH(K4,INDEX(TierSht!$B$2:$D$4,MATCH(C4,TierSht!$A$2:$A$4,0),0),1)),"")`

In the empty double quotes at the end, insert the text to display when no tier is selected. This will occur if `C4` was not found or `K4` was too low. You can replace `""` with

`IFNA(IF(MATCH(C4,TierSht!$A$2:$A$4,0),"Too Low"),"No Code")`

if there is a need to know which case occurred.